# ToolStripComboBox doesn't show the data unless bind the context?

Tags: c#

I have a question about ToolStripComboBox. When I used regular connection for example

```
sda.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT colName FROM tName,ConnectToString());
sda.Fill(dt);
ToolStripComboBox.ComboBox.DisplayMember = displayedName;
ToolStripComboBox.ComboBox.ValueMember = valueMember;
ToolStripComboBox.ComboBox.DataSource = dt;
```

It doesn't show up any data or linked to the database and it doesn't show any errors as well but when I add this line

```
combStore.ComboBox.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
```

It shows up the data but I don't really know what is the BindingContext can anybody explain and why I have to have it in my code to show the data?

Comment: where are you writing above code?

Comment: I'm here. How may I help you?